# How can i parse text from textBox and add each part of the text to a string variable?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

For example i type in the textNox: החטוף נמצא בתאריך: 25.6.2014 בשעה: 13:01

Then:

```
string t = בשעה: 13:01 
string f = בתאריך: 25.6.2014
string g = החטוף נמצא
```

This is a working code i did now the result/s is just what i needed:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> allwords = new List<string>();
            string firstPart = "";
            string secondPart = "";
            string thirdPart = "";
            int t = 0;
            textBox1.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            if (textBox1.Text.Contains("בתאריך"))
            {
                t = textBox1.Text.IndexOf("בתאריך");
                firstPart = textBox1.Text.Substring(0, t);
                allwords.Add(firstPart);
            }
            if (textBox1.Text.Contains("שעה"))
            {
                int x = textBox1.Text.IndexOf("שעה");
                secondPart = textBox1.Text.Substring(t, x-t);
                thirdPart = textBox1.Text.Substring(x);
                allwords.Add("דווח במקור " + secondPart + thirdPart);
            }

        }
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. How do you get to the strings t, f and g? Or is that what you want? Please make it more clear what your expected result is.

Comment: It was example. I want it to be like this that each part of text in the textBox will be in a string . I gave example of what i want it to be like.

Comment: The variable g should be the first to be assigned. I always type first the sentecense the text like: hello world then i type the date and time. So each time when i type something only when i type בתאריך then its the end of first part and this should be in a string. Then next time if i type בשעה then the part before untill this will be in a string. And last string will be from the בשעה to the end. And all this will be when i type in the textBox in real time using the textChanged event.

Comment: I don't want the Ok button. The parsing should be automatic while im typing in the textBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make more variables as you described, you can use a [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It's dynamic, so you can add or remove items from it. Each item can be accessed with proper indexes, starting from 0. I think you should create an "Add"-`Button` next to the `TextBox`, which creates a new string variable of the typed text to the list.

**Make a new list:**

```
List<string> texts = new List<string>();
```

**Then make the button and add new `Click`-method for it:**

```
public void myButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Add the text to the list
   texts.Add(yourTextBox.Text);

   // Then clear the TextBox for next input
   yourTextBox.Text = "";
}
```

**Ten you can loop through the list, accesing all the texts that were added:**

```
foreach (string text in texts)
{
   // Do something with the text...
}
```